# HTML Rubik's Cube Timer Code: Non-functional Buttons and Scramble Displayed as N/A on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, button, mobile

I have created a simple Rubik's cube timer web application with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It consists of a timer display, a scramble generator, and two buttons: one for starting/stopping the timer and another for resetting the timer and generating a new scramble sequence.

When I test this application on a PC, everything works as expected: the scramble generator produces a new sequence, and the buttons control the timer correctly. However, when I run the same application on a mobile device, I encounter two issues:

1. The scramble shows as "N/A" instead of generating a new sequence.
2. The buttons for starting the timer and resetting do not seem to be working.

And I'm using a android html viewer

and here is my code.

```js
        function generateScramble() {
            const moves = ["U", "F", "R", "L", "B", "D"];
            const suffixes = ["", "'", "2"];
            let scramble = "";
            let lastMove = -1;

            for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                let randomMove;
                do {
                    randomMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                } while (randomMove === lastMove);

                lastMove = randomMove;
                scramble += moves[randomMove] + suffixes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " ";
            }

            return scramble.trim();
        }

        document.getElementById('scramble').innerText = "Scramble: " + generateScramble();

        let timerStatus = 0;
        let timeStart;
        let elapsedTime = 0;
        let timerInterval;

        function displayTime(ms) {
            let minutes = Math.floor(ms / (1000 * 60));
            let seconds = Math.floor((ms % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            let milliseconds = Math.floor(ms % 1000);
            return (
                `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:` +
                `${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}.` +
                `${milliseconds.toString().padStart(3, '0')}`
            );
        }

        function updateTimerDisplay() {
            elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - timeStart;
            document.getElementById('timer').innerText = displayTime(elapsedTime);
        }

        document.getElementById('startBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (timerStatus === 0) {
                timerStatus = 1;
                timeStart = (new Date()).getTime() - elapsedTime;
                timerInterval = setInterval(updateTimerDisplay, 10);
            } else if (timerStatus === 1) {
                timerStatus = 0;
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('resetBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            timerStatus = 0;
            clearInterval(timerInterval);

            elapsedTime = 0;
            document.getElementById('timer').innerText = displayTime(elapsedTime);

            document.getElementById('scramble').innerText = "Scramble: " + generateScramble();
        });
```

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 50px;
            background-color: #F0F2F5;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #scramble {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #333;
        }
        #timer {
            font-size: 48px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: #333;
        }
        #resetBtn, #startBtn {
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 15px 30px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
        }
        #resetBtn {
            background-color: #F56565;
            color: white;
        }
        #startBtn {
            background-color: #48BB78;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>루빅스 큐브 타이머</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="scramble">Scramble: N/A</div>
        <div id="timer">00:00.00</div>
        <div>
            <button id="resetBtn">리셋</button>
            <button id="startBtn">시작</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I explored multiple StackOverflow articles and other resources related to similar issues, but none provided a solution. I expected the code to function properly on mobile devices, but the buttons remain unresponsive, and the Scramble text displays as N/A.

Comment: Which mobile phone and mobile browser are you using?

Comment: just default html viewer in android and using samsung A13

Comment: I don't have an A13, but running the code using the SO snippet on my S7+ in the Samsung browser worked OK. Does it fail in other mobile browsers?

Comment: Ummm I only have html viewer and no browser (the phone is made for having no wifi and have my file voice record radio call and message and camera gallery and clock and phone content, settings calendar calculator, Samsung notes, yt music.)

Comment: From [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58201/html-viewer-seems-not-running-the-websites-javascripts) it looks like HTMLViewer cannot run JavaScript. If you add `<noscript>javascript is disabled</noscript>` to your page, is it shown?

Comment: All of UI is shown correctly but the the function of button

Comment: That's because the css and html are processed but the javascript is not. The HTML viewer does not process javascript.

Comment: so its not possible?

Comment: From what I understand of the html viewer, it is not possible.